# Filling in username and password in iframe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am creating an application that should login you into different bookmakers site. I am having a trouble with marathonbet.co.uk . What I am doing is creating an iframe element inside container and filling in the login credentials. when I then click on the submit button it pops up the popup window that says something, what it used to say when you enter the blank credentials. I was trying to trigger all the different events upon  the login username textbox and password textbox, but it doesn't work...
Here is the code:

```
this.login = function() {
var self = this;
var dfd = $.Deferred();

this.interval = setInterval(function () {
  var $username = self.$iframe.contents().find('input[placeholder="Username"]');
  var $password = self.$iframe.contents().find('input[placeholder="Password"]');
  var $login = self.$iframe.contents().find('button[type="submit"].btn.btn_modern.btn_blue');
  if($username.length > 0 && $password.length > 0 && $login.length > 0) {
    $username.val(self.bookmaker.username);
    $password.val(self.bookmaker.password);
    $(".input").change();
    //$login.click();
    clearInterval(self.interval);
    dfd.resolve();
  }

}, 100);
return dfd.promise();
}

}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a proper problem statement and tells us next to nothing

Comment: "button[type="submit"].btn.btn_modern.btn_blue" is a pretty specific selector.  Are you sure the button is called this?  If you know the structure of the page - identifying the pieces should not require this level of precision and it makes the case brittle.  The user might decide to change the color to green.

Comment: I know, I just did it for testing.. Thank You for your advice...